# HibernateTransactionManager rollback transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

Im trying to update an entity

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test(){
    ChatState chatState = chatStateDAO.read(1L);
    chatState.setState(2);
    chatStateDAO.update(chatState);
    chatState.setState(2);
}
```

update method is calling hibernate session's `update()`. Here's what I have in my log

```
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE SessionImpl:219 - Opened session at timestamp: 14675565886
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE SessionImpl:1493 - Setting flush mode to: ALWAYS
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:210 - Updating detached instance
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:275 - Updating [ru.jeak.telegram.model.ChatState#1]
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:322 - Updating [ru.jeak.telegram.model.ChatState#1]
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE MyHibernateTransactionManager:943 - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2016-07-03 17:36:28 DEBUG MyHibernateTransactionManager:851 - Initiating transaction rollback
2016-07-03 17:36:28 DEBUG MyHibernateTransactionManager:597 - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2016-07-03 17:36:28 DEBUG TransactionImpl:86 - rolling back
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor:114 - Preparing to rollback transaction via JDBC Connection.rollback()
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor:117 - Transaction rolled-back via JDBC Connection.rollback()
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor:54 - LogicalConnection#afterTransaction
2016-07-03 17:36:28 TRACE ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:286 - Releasing JDBC resources
```

`MyHibernateTransactionManager` is default `HibernateTransactionManager`. I dont understand why this transaction gets rolled back without any error message or something?

Comment: @JBNizet Why not make that comment a answer? It seams a pretty good answer to me.

Comment: @DiogoSantana you're right. I often start as a short comment, but then I feel obligated to elaborate and my comment ends up being an answer. The OP doesn't seem to care, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `update()` to make the changes persistent. Changes to a managed entity are saved automatically. And `update()` is used to attach a **detached** entity to the session. Your entity is attached.

Regarding the rollback, Spring tests [automatically rollback](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#__rollback) at the end of the test, unless you tell Spring not to do it.

Comment: Yes, that is right. In my case update didn't worked because every DAO operation was opening a new session.